# Error when uploading images...directory doesn't exits

Tags: image, upload, plone

I'm trying to upload some photos into my Plone instance and it keeps giving me an error, which I don't quite understand.  I can't seem to find any documentation on it either.  Here is the error.

> "We’re sorry, but there seems to be an error…  Here is the full error
>   message:
>
> Display traceback as text
>
> Traceback (innermost last):
>
> Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish  Module
>   ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line
>   46, in call_object  Module Products.CMFPlone.FactoryTool, line 453, in
>   **call**  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object  Module
>   Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in
>   **call**  Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 28, in
>   _call  Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext  Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line
>   38, in **call**  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply  Module
>   ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object  Module
>   Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 107, in
>   **call**  Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext  Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line
>   38, in **call**  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply  Module
>   ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object  Module
>   Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPythonScript, line 105, in
>   **call**  Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in **call**  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in **call**  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in **call**  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec  Module
>   Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec  Module
>   script, line 1, in content_edit  
>   Line 1  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in **call** 
>   Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in **call**  Module
>   Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec  Module
>   Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec  Module
>   script, line 8, in content_edit_impl  
>   Line 8  Module Products.CMFPlone.FactoryTool, line 309, in doCreate 
>   Module Products.ATContentTypes.lib.constraintypes, line 277, in
>   invokeFactory  Module Products.CMFCore.PortalFolder, line 292, in
>   invokeFactory  Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 833, in
>   constructContent  Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 311, in
>   constructInstance  Module Products.CMFCore.TypesTool, line 552, in
>   _constructInstance  Module plone.app.blob.content, line 68, in addATBlobImage  Module plone.app.blob.content, line 59, in addATBlob 
>   Module Products.ATContentTypes.content.base, line 122, in
>   initializeArchetype  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseObject, line 439,
>   in setDefaults  Module Products.Archetypes.Schema, line 498, in
>   setDefaults  Module Products.Archetypes.utils, line 123, in mapply 
>   Module archetypes.schemaextender.field, line 38, in mutator  Module
>   plone.app.blob.subtypes.image, line 21, in set  Module
>   plone.app.blob.field, line 248, in set  Module transaction._manager,
>   line 101, in savepoint  Module transaction._transaction, line 260, in
>   savepoint  Module transaction._transaction, line 257, in savepoint 
>   Module transaction._transaction, line 690, in **init**  Module
>   ZODB.Connection, line 1123, in savepoint  Module ZODB.Connection, line
>   623, in _commit  Module ZODB.Connection, line 669, in _store_objects 
>   Module ZODB.blob, line 286, in _uncommitted  Module ZODB.blob, line
>   271, in _create_uncommitted_file  Module ZODB.utils, line 224, in
>   mktemp  Module tempfile, line 300, in mkstemp  Module tempfile, line
>   235, in _mkstemp_inner  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/usr/local/Plone/zeocluster/var/blobstorage/tmp/tmp2COObE'  "

**Does anyone know where I can start to debug this issue?**

Comment: my guess is permission

Comment: I should've mentioned it before but /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster doesn't exist.  It's as if the installation just didn't install all the proper directories no does it do it when I add a folder.  I can't upload files or images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If /usr/local/Plone/zeocluster doesn't exist, then you've got a zope/Plone instance running as a Zombie. The directory was probably deleted without stopping it. Find and kill the rogue processes. Then restart with the real install.

Comment: do you happen to know what this zombie instance might be called.  I can't find anything relating to plone, zope or ever plonectl.

Comment: Try "ps -auxwww | grep python" and see if you've got any background python proceeses.

Comment: I looked and as you suggested I had a background Zope instance running.  So I turned that off, wiped the Plone folder and reinstalled.  Which is great.  But now it's saying "ValueError: Unable to find update_version_before_edit" so I'm going to post that in another thread.